# Python - Apply changes to entire column

Tags: python, pandas, apply

What's the best way to modify all the values in an entire column?

This is what it looks like:

```
data.locations.head()    

0           [{'name': 'Chevy Chase, MD'}]
1                [{'name': 'Irvine, CA'}]
2    [{'name': 'San Francisco Bay Area'}]
3                 [{'name': 'Macon, GA'}]
4               [{'name': 'Fremont, CA'}]
Name: locations, dtype: object
```

I want to change it to this:

```
0           [{'Chevy Chase, MD'}]
1                [{'Irvine, CA'}]
2    [{'San Francisco Bay Area'}]
3                 [{'Macon, GA'}]
4               [{'Fremont, CA'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` with selecting first `dict` in `list` by `[0]` and then `key` `name`:

```
print (df.locations.apply(lambda x: [{x[0]['name']}]))
0           [{Chevy Chase, MD}]
1                [{Irvine, CA}]
2    [{San Francisco Bay Area}]
3                 [{Macon, GA}]
4               [{Fremont, CA}]
Name: locations, dtype: object
```

Comment: It says `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: What return `print (df.locations[df.locations.apply(len) == 0])` ?

Comment: `12    []`
`Name: locations, dtype: object`

Comment: I have an idea - can you send me your data as csv to my email in my profile if data not confidental? Or maybe filter only column locations to csv. It seem your data are problematic so your real can help me.

Comment: Now I am going to bed but tomorrow I try find solution. Thank you.